# does invokecommandaction use canexecute?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am new to wpf and interactivity. I am trying to execute a command based on some event trigger.  In the code below, when the doubleclick event is trigger, CanExecute is invoked and return false but the execute function is still called. Is this the default behavior for invokecommandaction? I would think that when can execute returns false, execute will not be called.

```
<UserControl x:Class="..."
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DisplayReportCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
...
```

Comment: Yes it does use canexecute and your command will not be executed if it is returning false. I tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will use the canexecute and command will not be execute if it return false. I have posted a code example.

Here is the command in your ViewModel class

```
RelayCommand _showMessageCommand;
public ICommand ShowMessageCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_showMessageCommand == null)
        {
            _showMessageCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.ShowMessage(), param => this.CanShowMessage);
        }
        return _showMessageCommand;
    }
}

public void ShowMessage()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Nitesh");
}

private bool CanShowMessage
{
    get
    {
        return false;    // Set to true to execute the command
    }
 }
```

and this is how you will use it in XAML

```
<Button Content="Nitesh">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ShowMessageCommand}" ></i:InvokeCommandAction>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: According to this site: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18199.event-handling-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application.aspx
"Also note that using the InvokeCommandAction doesn't automatically enable or disable the control based on the command's CanExecute method, unlike controls that have a Command property and can be bound directly to a command."

This seems to contradict what you wrote.  Which is true?